# Link in Nav won't work

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, navigation

I've tried to get the 'Stu' link to direct to index.html, but instead the click opens the nav drawer.

Try as I might, I can't fix it. 
I have a feeling it's something to do with the Javascript. Beyond my capabilities unfortunately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://stuseddon.co.uk/test/index.html

Comment: You should provide the relevant HTML, CSS, and javascript in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your pages:

```
$('a.navbar-brand').click(function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

It stops the click event from propagating to the link's parent which opens the "nav drawer" when clicked.